# In React, is there a way I can submit my search request only when someone stops typing?

Tags: reactjs, ajax, react-component

I'm using React 16.13.0.  I have this search box where people type and expect to see results as they type ...

```
return (
  <div className="searchForm">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search"
      value={this.state.searchTerm}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
```

I use the below functions to handle retrieving results as people type ...

```
  handleChange(event) {
    const query = event.target.value;
    if (!query) {
      this.setState({ searchTerm: query, searchResults: [] });
    } else {
      this.setState({ searchTerm: query, loading: true }, () => {
        this.doSearch(query);
      });
    }
  }

  doSearch = (query) => {
    const searchUrl = "/coops/?contains=" + encodeURIComponent(query);
    fetch(searchUrl, {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (query === this.state.searchTerm) {
          this.setState({
            searchResults: data,
            loading: false,
          });
        }
      });
  };
```

I'm trying to cut down on the amount of network calls being made/processed.  If someone types a string like "res" in a fairly rapid fashion, they probably don't care about the results for "r" or "re," so I was wondering, is there some way I can cancel a request if a new letter is entered in my search box?  Or only execute the search if someone has stopped typing for at least 100ms (not sure if this is enough time, but decided to pick an arbitrary amount)?

Comment: See JavaScripts ‘clearTimeout’ and ‘setTimeout’

Comment: Research "debounce".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after is usually called debounce. There is a number libraries that implement this functionality, incl. lodash and underscore.
In [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce), e.g., you would do the following:

```js
      onChange={e => debouncedHandler(e, this.handleChange)}
```

and defined the following *outside* of the component:

```js
const debouncedHandler = _.debounced((e, handler) => handler(e), 100);
```

It is a common pitfall to declare the debounced function inside the component itself. That will *not* work, because react reruns that code on every change and hence re-created the debounced function, hence the debouncing will not take place. Therefore it is important to define the debounced function outside the component.

---

Update: there was a mistake in the code I had earlier. It is fixed now, I think. I haven't tested this.

Comment: Hi, In "onChange={getDebouncedHandler(e, this.handleChange, 100)}", what is "e"?  I'm getting an undefined error when I try and add this into my onChange event for my textbox.

Comment: Actually there was another mistake in how/when I was creating the debounced function. I think it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the searching via `setTimeout`. Just clear the timeout whenever a new input is caught. If timer expires, go and do the request

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState(
        {
            searchTerm: e.target.value
        },
        () => {
            try {
                clearInterval(window.xhrSearchTimer);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(`no timeout initialized`);
            }

            window.xhrSearchTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
                this.doSearch(this.state.searchTerm);
            }, 1000); // arbitrary value
        }
    );
};

doSearch = () => {
    alert(`Now searching for ${this.state.searchTerm}`);
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-sid-hb0nr?file=/src/App.js:139-622

Answer (score 0):

You can use some helper like this and pass the calling function as the first argument `callback`.

```
function getDoneTyping (callback, wait = 300) {
  let timer
  const keyDownHandler = event => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      callback()
    }
    clearTimeout(timer)
  }

  const keyUpHandler = event => {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(callback, wait)
  }
  return { keyDownHandler, keyUpHandler }
}
```