# How to submit react form fields on onChange rather than on submit using React-Hook-Form library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have started using new React-Hook-form library and wanted to submit my input fields  on Change rather than on Submit. Also, I am planning to use debounce from Lodash to avoid re-rendering

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm();
 

  useEffect(() => {
    register({ name: "firstName" }, { required: true });
  }, [register]);

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        name="firstName"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue("firstName", e.target.value);
          handleSubmit((data) => console.log("data", data));
        }}
      />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: With that logic your form would submit as soon as user types a single character..is that what you're after?

Comment: Yeah, why do you want to submit form `onChange` in the first place? Let us know your thought process.

Comment: this would cause unnecessary rendering calling for each key press with onChange()  if the use case isn't to use onChange() . I recommend to use onSubmit() .

Comment: Here, I only care about the final state when user done with typing. So, I am planning to use debounce to avoid re-rendering.

Answer (score 58):

I found the simplest way to be:

```
const { handleSubmit, watch } = useForm();
const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data)

useEffect(() => {
    // TypeScript users 
    // const subscription = watch(() => handleSubmit(onSubmit)())
    const subscription = watch(handleSubmit(onSubmit));
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, [handleSubmit, watch]);
```

Comment: this should be accepted and highest voted answer

Comment: Agree. With a couple of minor corrections: missing = on `onSubmit` assignment; `watch` handler could be simplified to `watch(handleSubmit(onSubmit))`; `handleSubmit` should be part of dependency array.

Comment: The simplification suggested doest't work in Typescript, so Typescript users will need to use `watch(() => handleSubmit(onSubmit)())`

Answer (score 9):

If you log your implementation of `handleSubmit` inside `onChange`, you will notice that it returns a function

[image]

Try to invoke the returned function and it should submit.

```
onChange={(e) => {
    setValue("firstName", e.target.value);
    handleSubmit((data) => console.log("data", data))();
}}
```

I've also recently written my version of "user is done with typing, then submit" implementation for input fields - check it out:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63419790/8680805

Comment: what is the point of using react-hook-form if you're going to have an onChange function and have to set values manually

Answer (score 3):

From your example it looks like you only want to retrieve (all) the values after input change. Not sure if this will help you, but you can use the `getValues` function from the `useForm` hook.

```js
const Filters: FC<TProps> = ({ filters, setActiveFilter }) => {
  const { register, getValues } = useForm();

  const handleChange = () => {
    const values = getValues();
    // Do something with values, in my case I have used the 'setActiveFilter' function above.
  };

  return (
    <form>
      {filters.map((filter) => (
        <fieldset key={filter.id}>
          <legend>{filter.label}</legend>
          {filter.options.map((option) => (
            <label htmlFor={option.value} key={option.id}>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                id={option.value}
                name={filter.label}
                value={option.id}
                ref={register}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              {option.value}
            </label>
          ))}
        </fieldset>
      ))}
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

in react hook forms watch is the alternative way for onChange, simply do this:

```
const handleSubmit = (data) => {
 console.log(data)
}
    const {watch} = useForm();
    
          watch((data, { name }) => {
            if (name === "firstName") handleSubmit(data);
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

Alex answer not working in my case since I need a small delay before submiting form (when user stopped typing)

Here is my solution

```js
const { handleSubmit, watch } = useForm();
const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);


useEffect(() => {
 const subscription = watch(() => {
   if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);

   timer = setTimeout(() => {
     handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
   }, 1000);
 });
 return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, [handleSubmit, watch]);
```

Answer (score 1):

My two cents for a solution that may be targeting a full form. I'm simply using onChange on the form tag and it just work. You can also debounce it globally quite easily.

```
debounce(handleSubmit((data) => console.log("data", data)), 1500)
```

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  return (
    <form onChange={handleSubmit((data) => console.log("data", data))}>
      <input
        {...register("firstName")}
      />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score -2):

why do you want to submit it onChange?

but if you really want to do it, this should work:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, useWatch } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const { register, control, handleSubmit } = useForm()
  const firstName = useWatch({ control, name: 'firstName' })

  useEffect(() => {
    if(firstName && firstName.length > 0) {
      handleSubmit(data => console.log("data", data))()
    }
  }, [firstName, handleSubmit])

  return (
    <form>
      <input ref={register({ required: true })} name="firstName" />
    </form>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: FYI this solution results in an infinite rerender loop.